# move_base doesn't send cmd_vel

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I'm working on 4 wheels robot and I use `libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive.so`  as a controller now in the navigation stack whenI show the rqt graph I found that the move_base doesn't send a cmd_vel did this have a relation with the controller
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410703/move_base-doesn%27t-send-cmd_vel/) by [jandisoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/121744/jandisoon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Related ROS Q&A: https://answers.ros.org/question/392970/libgazebo_ros_skid_steer_drive-syntax-for-urdf-in-ros2/

And a nice tutorial: https://medium.com/ieee-manipal/ros-slam-path-planning-5f5d0b2c4cbc

You should have an RQT graph similar to this one

[image: image description]

Please check your steps and code, because something is possibly missing in it

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jandisoon](https://answers.ros.org/users/121744/jandisoon/) on 2022-12-21**:
thank you it's verry helpfull